# C# Update a plot chart with queue bound to it

Tags: c#, plot, data-binding, charts, queue

I want to make a real-time running chart to plot a diagram of incoming signals. Because I only want to display a number of the newest data, I thought of using a queue and bind it to the series. However, when I update my queue, the chart is not updated, and I don't know why.

Here is a simplified version of my code (it should "shift" the queue and refresh the chart for every click):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace PlotShiftExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Queue<double> dataSeries1;
        int xWindowSize = 5;
        double counter = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataSeries1 = new Queue<double>();

            chart1.Series.Clear();
            Series series1 = new Series
            {
                Name = "Series1",
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed,
                IsVisibleInLegend = false,
                IsXValueIndexed = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
            };

            chart1.Series.Add(series1);
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindY(dataSeries1);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataSeries1.Enqueue(counter++);

            if (dataSeries1.Count > xWindowSize)
                dataSeries1.Dequeue();

            chart1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use the same way of databinding in the buttonclick as you used before!

Answer (score -1):

you should have to take timer and bind chart every time tick event.